# how to insert datetime in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently creating an application. I have created a form where the user is able to choose a year,month,day,hour and minute. I was wondering how to insert this into my sql database. Thanks

code for the form-

```
           <select name="day" id="day">
 <?php
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) 
{
echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<td>
<select name="month" id="month">

  <?php
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) 
{
echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<td>

<select name="year" id="year">
  <?php
for($i=2015;$i<=2016;$i++) 
{
echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
}
?>
  <td>
  </select>

    <select name="Hour" id="hour">
 <?php
for($i=0;$i<=23;$i++) 
{
echo "<option>" . sprintf("%02d",$i) . "</option>";
}
?>

</select>
<td>
<select name="minute">
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=60;$i++) 
{
echo "<option>" . sprintf("%02d",$i) . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You really need to learn how forms work. Here http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php - This is the basic of forms handling. You haven't shown us anything that you tried; just dropping code and asking "how". This question could have easily been avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You put this in a [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)**(read everything from this link**) and then use $_POST['day'] etc and use an insert query to put it in the database. I wont say too much about this since
I wouldn't recommend doing it like this at all.

You're checking the days of the month. If it has less than 31 days in it, it's valid. < **This is not true. Not all the dates are valid if it has less than 31 days in it.** There's ways to do this which already exist. It's so much easier. [PHP datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). You can also validate most with the [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type in mysql. I'd recommend you to read through all of the links.