# how to insert date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So far i have created drop downs for year,month and day. I have used php to insert the data in mysql database but it does not work, the dates are not inserting into the database, it is really annoying as i don't know what the problem is. Would love some help please. thanks

form code

```
<form method=post name=f1 action=''><input type=hidden name=todo value=submit>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr><td align=left >
<select name=month value=''>Select Month
<option value='01'>January</option>
<option value='02'>February</option>
<option value='03'>March</option> etc..
```

I have done the same for day and year.

php code

```
require("common.php"); 
<?php
$todo=htmlentities($_POST['todo']);
if(isset($todo) and $todo=="submit"){
$month=htmlentities($_POST['month']);
$dt=htmlentities($_POST['dt']);
$year=htmlentities($_POST['year']);
$date_value="$month/$dt/$year";
echo "mm/dd/yyyy format :$date_value<br>";
$date_value="$year-$month-$dt";
echo "YYYY-mm-dd format :$date_value<br>";
}

$m=$month;
$d=$dt;
$y=$year;
If(!checkdate($m,$d,$y)){
echo "invalid date";
}else {
echo "Entry date is correct";
}
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (dates)
VALUES
('$_POST[$date_value])"; 

     mysql_query($sql);


      exit();  

?>
```

Comment: $date_value is not part of the $_POST[] variable.

Comment: @Nadia mysql accept only Y-m-d format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert datetime in mysql using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813536/how-to-insert-datetime-in-mysql-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your insert query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (dates) VALUES ('$date_value')";
```

Comment: Very nice security flaw.

Comment: A. It's wrong and B. You never should put user input directly in a query, escape or use a prepared statement.

Comment: @jeroen i have just corrected the insert query for posted answer

Comment: Hi. i have used the code you have given me. The date turns out to be 0000-00-00 in the database.

Comment: what did you give in $_POST['date_value']?

Comment: There is no `$_POST['date_value']`, there are 3 different inputs for the different parts of the date.

Comment: @jeroen so he can give name to input box like the same

Comment: @Nadia you can use jquery date picker plugin too

Comment: @Nadia I'm confused, how can inserting an undefined variable in your database be the solution?

Comment: i have changed my answer. please see @jeroen

Comment: It seemed to work for the OP :-) Anyway, to avoid sql injection, you might want to add that that whole section should be placed inside the `else` statement.

Comment: @jeroen but now there should no down votes. because i have edited my answer

Comment: hi. i just wanted to put a date into mysql database through user input @jeroen

Comment: That's up to the individual downvoters. You still have an sql injection problem.

Comment: @Nadia then you can use jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: @jeroen that depends on user who posted the question.

Comment: @noddy i am not allowed to use plugins in my project.

Comment: @Nadia then just give one input box and force user to insert date in 'Y-m-d' format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this just concat the date like below

```
$month=htmlentities($_POST['month']);
$dt=htmlentities($_POST['dt']);
$year=htmlentities($_POST['year']);
$date_value=$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$dt;

$sql="INSERT INTO survey (dates) VALUES ('".$date_value."')";
```

Comment: may be for this - ('".$_POST[$date_value]."').. $date_value in $_POST

Comment: Security flaw. Again.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[$date_value] is not a part of $_POST !!!

```
$date_value="$year-$month-$dt";
```

so replace your $_POST[$date_value] in the INSERT quert with $date_value

like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (dates) VALUES ('".$date_value."')";
```

Comment: Nice security flaw here, too.

Comment: @BinaryBrain This would actually be sort of okay if that whole section was inside the `else` statement where it should be anyway.

Comment: Maybe, but common, you know this is a very bad practice. Just use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @BinaryBrain I'm trying just to fix the issue with the query, but if we talk about security you're right " Never Trust User Input"

Comment: @BinaryBrain Of course, but checking for a valid date and then injecting it in a query is *sort of okay*. However, ditching `mysql_*` and using a prepared statement would definitely be better but that is up to the OP.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO employee '.
       '(emp_name,emp_address, emp_salary, join_date) '.
       'VALUES ( "guest", "XYZ", 2000, NOW() )';

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

this may help you out..

Comment: Are you sure this answer is meant for this question? They don't seem related.